# Deserializar para um ICollection sem a necessidade de criar uma classe extra

Tags: .net, json, json.net

Olá. Estou usando Json.NET para deserializar meu objeto. Hoje eu faço da seguinte forma:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<TModelo>>(stream.ReadToEnd());`

Atualmente eu tenho que criar uma classe extra (`Produtos`) pois o retorno é um array. Dentro da Classe `Produtos` então eu tenho:

```
[JsonProperty("products")]
public ICollection<Produto> ListaProdutos { get; set; }
```

Dessa forma estou conseguindo deserializar. A minha questão é: Existe outra forma de eu fazer isto sempre precisar da classe `Produtos`? Ou seja, fazer com que essa conversão seja "automática" sem a necessidade de uma classe adicional?

Falo isto porque tenho várias classes (se trata de uma API) e gostaria de uma forma mais elegantes de trabalhar isto.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o próprio [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) que já está sendo utilizado tem o modo esse modo dinâmico, ele utiliza LINQ:

```
 json = @"{name: 'Leonardo', lastname: 'Bonetti'}";
 JObject jObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
 Debug.WriteLine((String)jObject["name"]); //Leonardo
```

Caso você tenha apenas um `Array` por exemplo também é possível Deserializar diretamente:

```
string json = @"['Small', 'Medium','Large']";
JArray a = JArray.Parse(json);
Debug.WriteLine((int)a.Count);//3
```

Você também pode ler direto de um arquivo através do StreamReader:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"c:\meuJson.json"))
{
    JObject o = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(reader));
}
```

Fonte e outros exemplo: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm

Ou você pode utilizar a mesma abordagem de cima junto ao recurso [dynamic](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic)(é um tipo de variável que ignora verificação de tipo na compilação, esse processo acontece durante a execução ou seja, ele é dinâmico, porém tem o lado negativo pois alguns métodos não aceitam tipos dinâmicos) que fica um pouco mais legível:

Exemplo de acesso a objeto:

```
string json = @"{name: 'Leonardo', lastname: 'Bonetti'}";
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);
String name = obj.name; //Leonardo
```

Exemplo de acesso a uma variável direta:

```
 string json = @"['Small', 'Medium','Large']";
 dynamic obj = JArray.Parse(json);
 int name = obj.Count; //Leonardo
```

Exemplo de acesso lendo diretamente do StreamReader:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"c:\meuJson.json"))
{
    dynamic obj = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(reader));
}
```

Fonte da utilização do `dynamic`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net

Comment: Dessa forma não consigo manter a linha `[JsonProperty("products")]` que se faz necessária pra que ao deserializar a aplicação saiba que o array tem esse nome (`products`).